# Can a Union of Disjoint Paths be Considered a Set of Vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Say we have a graph $G=\{E,V\}$ and set of disjoint directed paths $p_K$, if all the disjoint directed paths utilize all the vertices of the graph $G$, does it imply $ \cup_{p_k}=V$?

Comment: No, we cannot say that because I do not feel like saying that.  You  can say that if you like but speak for yourself only.  Your question is tagged wrong.  Tag it graphs.

Comment: Can you elaborate why cant we say that all unions of paths form the full vertices of the graph?

Comment: For us, you and I, to be able to say that requires both of to be willing to say that.  As I am not willing to say that, we together cannot say that.

Comment: I was talking more on semantic correctness then on will or feel.

Comment: Your question is clear, coherent, understandable, and  unambiguous.  In other words, semantically correct.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I see. Am I missing something? Please do care to point out, it will help me correct my mistake/s.

Comment: You should see by now that "Can we say that   happens?" is much  different than  "Does that happen?" The first is talking about cooperative  group action;  the other is asking about a fact.

Comment: Ah +1, it makes sense. Was critical mistake. I changed it to "does it imply" not really 100% sure if its the right wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path is a set of edges.
The union of a set of edges is a set of edges.
So it is not a set of vertices.
Two paths are disjoint when they have no edges in common. 
They can have common vertices.

It is trivial to show that the union of the vertices of a collection of disjoint paths of a graph, directed or not directed, that use all the vertices of the graph, is the set of all the vertices.

Give an example of a graph, directed or not directed, for which the union of the  vertices of a collection of disjoint paths, that use all the edges of the graph is not the set of all the vertices.

What minimum condition upon the graph would assure that the above union is the set of all the vertices?

Comment: +1 for nice explanation and apologies for late correspondence, had critical issue to take care of. Your answer is exactly what I am looking for. I however couldnt construct the graph for which union of the vertices of a collection of disjoint paths which uses all the edges of the graph but not all the vertices. Shouldnt the graph with disjoint paths that uses all the edges of the graph should also cover union of all the vertices. Afterall the edge joins vertices of the graph and all the edges would mean all the vertices by default. Right?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER.  Let the graph be a single vertex with no edges or with a loop.

Comment: Allright, for the graph with single vertex, there is no path. I am not really following, yet I really like your approach of simulating my thought process. The minimum condition would that the graph must be cyclic to have union of all path vertices be set of all the vertices of the graph. Correct?